# Accessing attributes from different associated models rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I am looking to get a better understanding of Active Model/Record relationships and how to call attributes dependent upon where the attributes are located (models) and where I am calling them. So for example I can access the attribute dish_name from within the recipe controller like so

```
 def all_recipes
@recipes = Recipe.all
 end
```

In the view

```
<% @recipes.each do |r| %>
<%= r.dish_name %>
<% end %>
```

Now say i want to access a recipe attribute from within my controller called worldrecipes and i have just written a method that returns all recipes with the same country. a country has many recipes as a relation

So my method is

```
def self.top_countries
joins(:recipes).
  select('countries.*, count(*) AS recipes_count').
  group('countries.id').
  order('recipes_count DESC')
 end
```

My controller

```
@worldrecipes = Country.where(:name => params[:name])
```

and view

```
<% @worldrecipes.each do |r|  %>
<%= r.name %>
<% end %>
```

so accessing the country name attribute is easy as its in the country model and thats where my query results are being returned from (I think)...My question is how do i access the dish_name attribute from my recipe model to that links to the country name

Hope that makes sense, does anyone have a guide on how to work this out or some golden rules for this

Thank you

Comment: Does `@worldrecipes = Country.where(:name => params[:name])' give you the country record with name as `params[:name]` or the array of recipes for that country??

Comment: it gives me the record name as params[:name] as in my view i get the word "Italy" printed on the page, which isnt totally correct as there are 2 records with Italy and only one is being displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you want to make sure you have the association setup in your models:

**country.rb**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :recipes
end
```

**recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :country
end
```

If you haven't already done so, add a foreign_key attribute to your recipe model by running the following migration:

```
rails g migration add_country_id_to_recipe country_id:integer
```

Now that your associations are in place you can easily query for a countries respective recipes. In your controller:

```
@worldrecipes = Country.where(:name => params[:name])
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @worldrecipes.each do |c|  %>
  <% c.recipes.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.dish_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

In regards to 'golden rules' I highly recommend you check out [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). This is the go-to place for an overview of what you can do with associations.

Comment: You need not use includes when pulling the country from the database. Its probably gonna waste memory and there is usually only one country, if you know what I am talking about.

Comment: ok so theres a nested block and now im confused by the output, its printed out all of my recipes with all of its attributes, my associations are as you have stated, they have been setup like that from the beginning

Comment: remove the `=` from line 2 in the view

Comment: @stevanity Right, I'll leave optimization up to the OP. Oh, and good catch on the `=`. See updated view code.

Comment: hang out a sec im getting the dish names for each recipe for italy printed out... thanks guys, what documentation can i read to understand this?

Comment: See the last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: thankk you both for your input, thank you @cyle, seeing your example has helped, didnt even know you could nest blocks

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need is:

```
@country=Country.where(:name=>params[:name]).first
@worldrecipes=@country.recipes
```

And in the view:

```
<% @worldrecipes.each do |r|  %>
  <%= r.dish_name %>
<% end %>
```

This would print the dish names of the recipes of the country with name provided by `params[:name]`

EDIT:
Ok Let me clear this up for you :)

Your model relationship is setup such that each country has many recipes. i.e a country has many recipes.

So you have,

```
has_many :recipes
```

in country.rb and

```
belongs_to :country
```

in recipe.rb

Now when you want to access all the recipes belonging to a country, what you do is, you call `country_record.recipes` (country_record being the object of the country record you need).

And when you call,
    Country.where(:name=>params[:name])
What you actually get is the active record object representing the COUNTRY itself and not the recipes of the country and that is why Italy was printed.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: now i get undefined method `recipes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x96983c8>

Comment: check your model files. Have you created the relations?

Comment: relations are as you have stated

Comment: your answer works aswell, sorry i cant mark both... your way does seem cleaner though?